# Undefined symbols for architecture i386: "_OBJC_IVAR_$_UIViewController._view", referenced from:

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode4

I've been looking through countless posts about this error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_IVAR_$_UIViewController._view", referenced from:
      -[ViewController viewDidLoad] in ViewController.o

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I already checked .m file and link libraries and copy bundle file. i am using xcode 4.6.2 version. i want to make programmatically Button in ViewDidLoad.

Comment: You checked the linked libraries and... what was the result?  You aren't missing UIKit are you?

Comment: @borrrden In libraries, i have three item including UIKit

Comment: @user1992553: Please check whether ViewController.m is present in `Compile sources` in your project target.

Comment: @Deepesh thanks ,i already told that ViewController.m (.m) file is present in compile sources in project target

Comment: @user1992553 check whether you have imported .m file instead of .h

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is uncertainty for the exact reason but there may be many reasons for this error:

1. Either the button isn't instantiated (allocated & initialized) i.e. button is nil.
2. If you have made button globally then access it using **self**

Ex:

```
myButton = [[UIButton alloc] init];// Don't use like this
self.myButton = [[UIButton alloc] init];// Use like this
```

**EDIT :**
replace your code with this

```
self.button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
self.button.frame = CGRectMake(10, 220, 150, 30);
[self.button setTitle:@"Show" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.button addTarget:self action:@selector(aMethod:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[_view addSubview:self.button]; // Note if you have set property of _view then use it as self.view because it also may be the cause of error.
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: i'm getting the same problem

Comment: Can you post the code you are using in viewdidload for creating button?

Comment: self.button = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 220, 150, 30)];
    [button setTitle:@"Show" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [button addTarget:self
               action:@selector(aMethod:)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
     [_view addSubview:button];

Comment: @Sultania check my updated answer edit section. and replace your code with this and check.

Comment: It's definitely not reason 1. It's a linking error not a runtime error.

Answer (score 3):

are you referencing self.view by using _view notation? that could be the problem. try switching out _view for self.view

Comment: Thank you! Just happened to me in XCode6. Such an unhelpful error generated by this.

Comment: I wish I could give you more thumbs up! what a stupid compiler error!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you are using the

```
_viewYour.doSomething
```

not

```
_view.doSomething
```

I made this mistake just now.